# PHPunit I can't rollback

Tags: phpunit

I'm having issue with my transactions. I gotta open one at the `setup()`, so far I can do it and then rollback it with `TearDown()`. The problem is that I can't access to my connection `($dbh)` from `teardown()`.

```
class PanneauTest extends TestCase
{
    private $http;
    private $token;
    private $dbh;


    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->http = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 
    'http://localhost/rocourt/01-Backend/api/v1/public/']);

        $this->token = User::login('toto', '1234');

        $this->dbh = getConnection();
        $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        //I can't use the dbh->rollback()from this function 
    }
```

Comment: Try the uses the `setUpBeforeClass()` and `tearDownAfterClass()` template methods as described in the [Sharing Fixture](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.sharing-fixture) section of the docs